# How to pass arguments to application.java class in Apache Apex?

Tags: java, apache-apex

How can I pass arguments to `Application.java` class ? Like how we pass `(String[] args)` in main method in java ?

Couldn’t find any references. Can someone please share knowledge on this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments as Configuration. This configuration will be passed as an argument to populateDAG() method in Application.java.

Configuration is `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`. You can specify it as xml. For xml syntax please refer to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html.

There are different ways in which properties can be specified:

1. `~/.dt/dt-site.xml`: By default apex cli will look for this file (~ is your home directory). You should use this file for the properties which are common to all the applications in your environment.
2. `-conf` option on apex cli: launch command on apex cli provides `-conf` option to specify properties. You need to specify the path for the configuration xml. You should use this file for the properties which are specific to a particular application or specific to this launch of the application.
3. `-Dproperty-name=value`: launch command on apex cli provides -D option to specify properties. You can specify multiple properties like -Dproperty-name1=value1 -Dproperty-name2=value2 etc.

Syntax for specifying operator properties is as follows:

```
<property>
      <name>dt.application.applicationName.operator.OperatorIdentifier.prop.property-name1</name>
      <value>value1</value>
</property>  

<property>
      <name>dt.application.applicationName.operator.OperatorIdentifier.prop.property-name2</name>
      <value>value2</value>
</property>
```

OperatorIdentifier/name is the String identifier you use for dag.addOperator() in the populateDAG().

Comment: Thanks @Yogi Devendra

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer only describes in detail how to specify **operator** properties or with using `~/.dt/dt-site.xml` or Apex CLI, here is one simple example how to specify properties that you can use in the `Application.java` (i.e. in the `populateDag()` Method).

Specify the properties in XML in the file: `resources/META-INF/properties.xml` like this:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- Specify some arbitrary app configs -->
  <property>
    <name>prop1</name>
    <value>val1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>prop2</name>
    <value>val2</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Specify some other configs, i.e. operator properties -->
  <property>
    <name>dt.application.applicationName.operator.OperatorIdentifier.prop.property-name1</name>
    <value>value1</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Then in your `Application.java` you can get the properties like this:

```
public class Application implements StreamingApplication
{

  @Override
  public void populateDAG(DAG dag, Configuration conf)
  {
    String prop1 = conf.get("prop1");
    String prop2 = conf.get("prop2", "defaultValue"); // when the property is not set in XML, a default can be used

    // populate your DAG here ...
  }
}
```

Instead of using operator properties, this approach can be very useful if you need properties in operators before the `setup()` method is executed, for instance in the constructor of an operator.